# .NET Core environment variables in source control

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm learning to work with the .NET Core 5.0 framework and was reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows#string-replacement-with-secrets) about managing user secrets. Coming from Node.js, I'm used to `.env` files where for example database connections credentials are stored.

When looking at boilerplates, such as [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) or [clean-architecture-manga](https://github.com/ivanpaulovich/clean-architecture-manga/), I notice the database connection string still being in the `appsettings.json`, which isn't in located in the  `.gitignore` file.

```
"PersistenceModule": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;User Id=sa;Password=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>;Database=Accounts;"
},
```

Am I misunderstanding something about uset secrets in ASP.NET?
Is the database password the same for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0).  In .Net Core secrets can be inserted into a the appsettings.json file from environment variables via the command line on start up as long as the appsettings.json file is properly tokenized. There's also the ability to override the appsettings.json file with values stored in a key vault, such as Hashicorp Vault or Microsoft's Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Doesn't that still mean the password will be inside of the `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: no.  the property would be there, but the actual value of the password will not be.  that would be stored in the key vault or in an env variable.  whichever you choose to go with.  I've also worked at a place that did store the passwords in a file that was not part of source control which they would then overwrite the values in the appsettings that was in source control.  I'm not sure which way is best.  I would assume key vault is the best choice.